# Add gallery(with Lightbox) to tinymce using unsharp file manager and laravel

Tags: laravel, gallery, lightbox

I am using Laravel 5.2.* and have integrated the Tinymce4 WYSIWYG and I am using unisharp file manager http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/

I have not been able to find documentation that will allow me to add a gallery yet. Adding an image to the editor works perfectly but a 3 column gallery is not possible.

I would like to add a feature similar to how a user can add galleries in WordPress. I would like to also be able to make the images clickable where they open a lightbox.

Could someone please point me in the correct direction